# Wireguard is blocked in Iran , what can I do?

Tags: vpn, wireguard

### Brief description :

I think Wireguard is blocked from special datacenters like Hetzner.

How can I bypass the government firewall?

Is there a way, for example, a plugin or something to mix it with original wireguard to get it to work?

### Details (story):

I have a VPS from Hetzner datacenter.

I have set up a [Wireguard](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/wireguard) using docker in my server, and when I want to connect to it in the client, Wireguard connects, but there is no internet.

[image]

and here is its log :

[image]

Then in my laptop, [I shared a free VPN connection to a Hotspot network adapter of my laptop.](https://youtu.be/OAXyDufGK0E)

And then in my android phone, I connect to wifi.

So, my android phone is provided with the internet which is already tunnelled.

And then in my phone, when I try connecting to Wireguard again, it connects correctly with the internet!

So I am sure that the problem is not from my server or VPN implementation, but from my country's firewall.

There is another strange thing that I should say, these protocols have a problem only when they are hosted in specific datacenters (like Hetzner).

For example, I have a working L2TP on my laptop that is hosted in Japan.

But my Hetzner hosted L2TP does not connect! (but it connects from my Hotspot!)

I think for wireguard it is true the same.

### My Tries

I can use Shadowsocks based proxies like [V2Ray](https://www.v2fly.org/en_US/), [Trojan](https://github.com/trojan-gfw/trojan) and [this](https://privacymelon.com/how-to-setup-v2ray-ws-tls-cdn/), etc.

But they are proxies and not a VPN, they don't tunnel my whole device.

Even if I enter proxy in my Internet Options in Windows10, the programs which use Sockets are not provided with tunnelled Internet. Programs like AmongUs, Mail, etc.

Also, I tried using domain instead of using IP in the configuration.

I thought when I use a domain which is configured in Cloudflare CDN, my Server IP does not expose and it could help my VPN to connect, but I was wrong.

By the way, I have tried OpenVPN, PPTP, L2TP and Wireguard (none of them worked).

### Question

What should I do?!

I appreciate if you give me any ideas to get my Wireguard to work.

Or if you could suggest any other VPN protocol.

Comment: Wireguard can be tunneled within various other protocols. See for example [Wireguard over Websockets](https://github.com/jnsgruk/wireguard-over-wss).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you ! I will check that out !

Comment: Did you try running it on different ports? You can run WireGuard on any port. This may be simpler than tunnelling.

Comment: Any update? what did you end up doing?

Comment: @KennetCeleste I gave up and used Outline instead